# Do iWork applications now iOS support versioning?

Tags: ios, iwork

The current iWork on Lion supports autosave and versions. Is the same true for the iOS versions of these applications? I need versioning support for my documents on iOS devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version support is not found in iWork it is actually a part of OSX Lion. There is no version support built into iOS. (yet)

Comment: After some research, I found a nice talk from this year's WWDC, where versions and autosave are explained. It only mentions OS X as well. iCloud also seems to store only one version of a file. https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#auto-save-and-versions-in-mac-os-x-10_7-lion

Comment: Thanks for adding the link, I will watch this when I have a spare min.